# How to replace the old image with the cropped new image it

Tags: python, pandas, shutil

Currently learning reading image by csv and crop it with the data in the csv

the csv has data like below

```
filename    width   height  class   xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax
Data16_173_55.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  476.25  100.14815   518.125 148.03148
Data16_173_56.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  474.68753   95.14074    517.1875    153.0389
Data16_173_57.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  468.125 93.26296    518.125 149.5963
Data16_173_58.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  470.3125    101.08704   519.0625    148.34444
```

and i am currently trying to crop it and replace the image using looping code by reading the filename, here's the **code**

```
import shutil
import os
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')
for index, row in data.iterrows():
  input_name  = os.path.join("imagesXRP", row["filename"])
  xmin  = row["xmin"]
  ymin = row['ymin']
  xmax  = row["xmax"]
  ymax = row['ymax']
  im = Image.open(input_name)
  im1 = im.crop((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
  im1.save(input_name'*.jpg')
```

but i am still dont get how to replace the old image with the new cropped one using that `input_name`

any answer would be help

thank you so much !

UPDATE:
The error now become

`OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'imagesXRP/Data16_173_55.jpg'`

Comment: `im1.save(input_name'*.jpg')` => `im1.save(input_name)`?

Comment: @Marat Thanks it works, but now it got Input/Output error:(, please make it as an answer, thank you

Comment: Can you post the error please?

Comment: @Marat done edited, but the topic in this post are about the im1.save, so if you want to post your comment as answer is fine too for me, i can make it as the answer for this post too

Comment: add `im.close()` before saving `im1`

Comment: @Marat still have teh same error

Answer (score 0):

I think I know your answer
You need a csv file for this.
In that file, there are four numbers that are the coordinate points on your photo, so your photo will be cropped first, then the photo will be saved with the cropped dimensions.
The task of this code is to receive an image from a camera, crop and save that image
I wrote this code and it works:

```
import csv
import cv2
import queue, threading

with open('option.csv', newline='') as option:
    reader = csv.reader(option)
    option = list(reader)
global ipcam1
ipcam1=option[0][0]
global camUser1
camUser1=option[2][0]
global camPass1
camPass1=option[4][0]

class VideoCapture:
    try :     
      def __init__(self, name):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
        self.cap.open(name)
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self._reader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
      # read frames as soon as they are available, keeping only most recent one
     
      def _reader(self):
        while True:
          ret, frame = self.cap.read()
          if not ret:
            break
          if not self.q.empty():
            try:
              self.q.get_nowait()   # discard previous (unprocessed) frame
            except queue.Empty:
              pass
          self.q.put(frame)

    except :
        print("exit")
    def read(self):
        return self.q.get()

    
url1='rtsp://'+camUser1+':'+camPass1+'@'+ipcam1+':554/Streaming/channels/1/'
cap1= VideoCapture(url1)

while True:
    with open("croping_image_1.csv",newline="",) as cropi:
        reader = csv.reader(cropi)
        cropi = list(reader)
        frame = cap1.read()
        frame = frame[int(cropi[0][0]):int(cropi[1][0]), int(cropi[2][0]):int(cropi[3][0])]
        cv2.imwrite("screen.jpg", frame)

    break
```